# Prototype Toggle through Array Only Toggling Last Item

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, prototype

I'm a beginner and my brother has showed me some prototype.  All the weeks successfully toggle the last week in the array but no other.  Please let me know if I need to be more specific!  Thanks!

```
<%= @athletic_program.program_name %>
<br>
<br>

<% array of_ids = Array.new %>

<% @program_weeks.each do |program_week| %>
  <% array_of_ids.push(program_week.id) %>
  <div id="week_number_<%= program_week.id %>" class="week_number">Week <%=program_week.week_number %></div>
<div id="program_week_form_<%= program_week.id %>" class="program_week_form">
    <% form_for(program_week) do |f| %>
      <%= f.error_messages %>
      Number of Workouts <%= f.select :number_of_workouts, (1..7), {} %>
      <%= f.submit 'Next' %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
<% end %>

<% content_for :javascript do %>
<script type="text/javascript">
function showForms(array_of_ids){
  for(var i=0;i<array_of_ids.length;i++){
    id = array_of_ids[i];
    week_id = "week_number_" + array_of_ids[i];
    $(week_id).onclick = function(event){
      program_form = "program_week_form_" + id;
      form_div = $(program_form);
      if (form_div.style.display == 'none'){
        form_div.style.display = 'block';
      } else {
        form_div.style.display = 'none';
      }
    }
  }
}

showForms(<%= array_of_ids.to_json %>);
</script>
<% end %>
```

The following now works!

```
<%= @athletic_program.program_name %>
<br>
<br>

<% @program_weeks.each do |program_week| %>
  <div id="week_number_<%= program_week.id %>" class="week_number" onclick="$('program_week_form_<%= program_week.id %>').toggle()">Week <%=program_week.week_number %></div>
  <div id="program_week_form_<%= program_week.id %>" class="program_week_form" style="display:none;">
    <% form_for(program_week) do |f| %>
      <%= f.error_messages %>
      Number of Workouts <%= f.select :number_of_workouts, (1..7), {} %>
      <%= f.submit 'Next' %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

I added style="display:none;" to the program_week_form_ to have it hidden by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you simply trying to toggle the form when the week div is clicked?  In that case you are really going about this the wrong way.

I think you can remove all your javascript and your array_of_ids and just change the week div to this if you're using Prototype:

```
<div id="week_number_<%= program_week.id %>" class="week_number" onclick="$('program_week_form_<%= program_week.id %>').toggle()">Week <%=program_week.week_number %></div>
```

Comment: Thank you!  I put an extra single quote inside of the onclick method and it works!  Thanks again!

Comment: I was under the impression that it was better to no put javascript inline, but that was mainly due to advice in the IRC chat and I never understood why.  What are your thoughts?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/543790/rails-inline-javascript-and-best-practices

Comment: @todd, good catch.  sorry about that :)

@tenjack, you're right.  best practice is to write unobtrusive JS, but given the original code an the fact that the OP is just starting with Prototype/JS I think this was a simple step forward.